# Duda Secret Key en proyecto Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

recientemente recibí un proyecto ya empezado de Python y Django, la cosa es que al tratar de arrancar el servidor me da el siguiente error:

```
   PS C:\Users\jmtorices\Documents\shpssl-main> py manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 403, in get_value
    value = self.ENVIRON[var_name]
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\os.py", line 680, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\Documents\shpssl-main\manage.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\Documents\shpssl-main\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 66, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 73, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 71, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 179, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\Documents\shpssl-main\shpssl\settings\production.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\Documents\shpssl-main\shpssl\settings\base.py", line 39, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 197, in __call__
    return self.get_value(
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 407, in get_value
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg) from exc
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable
```

Deduzco que puede ser algo rollo a que la persona implantó una clave y no la tenemos, pero al intentar escribir otra clave continua dándonos otros errores como  KeyError: 'EMAIL_HOST' o KeyError: 'DATABASE_NAME'

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Más que seguro son variables de entorno que debes de establecer

Comment: Quizá te falte añadirla variable SECRET_KEY = "..." en el settings del proyecto.

Comment: En efecto parece ser un problema de variables de entorno,  revisastes que tienes el archivo .env o el requerido por la librería django-environ? O has intentado imprimir los valores de esas variables a ver si se están leyendo correctamente desde su origen.

Comment: La variable si que está definida en base.py dentro de la carpeta settings, algo así como SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

Comment: El proyecto no venía con ningún archivo .env, no se si puedo crearle yo o me lo tenían que haber pasado? A que te refieres con imprimir el valor de las variables? print(SECRET_KEY) desde el shell o alguna forma así?